# Eclipse debugger not working - automatically terminating (MingGW) CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I'm attempting to debug a simple application in CDT using the MinGW, i.e. Hello World.
It builds and runs correctly;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

With the following options: 
[image]

However, when I run the debugger, it simply jumps over any breakpoints with no output, errors or stopping whatsoever (making me think that it hasn't actually run at all) straight to: `terminated`
[image]

Any ideas whats causing this and how I can go about fixing it?

Thanks very much!

David

**UPDATES**

I don't think it can be an error with GDB? As when when run from the cmd line it appears to work correctly.

[image]

Comment: Try running in the console, you are probably having a dll error?

Comment: @JonahGraham I tried running from console and it seemed to be correct?

Comment: I have seen this kind of error before and it has always been dll type problems, i.e. the environment CDT is using to launch GDB is not correct. I notice your update shows HelloWorld.exe in C:\Mingw\bin, did you move it there to get it to work. PS what I normally do when using MinGW is launch Eclipse from within the MinGW installed shell so that Eclipse inherits that environment, rather than Eclipse trying to reconstruct it.